# Cross-account monitoring using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I'd like to enable cross-account monitoring in Cloudwatch using AWS CDK. From the Cloudformation docs it seems there are two resources - Sink and Link and having those two is enough to enable that. But it just doesn't work and I don't understand why.

```js
const monitoringAccountPolicyDocument = new PolicyDocument({
      statements: [
        new PolicyStatement({
          effect: Effect.ALLOW,
          actions: ["oam:*"],
          resources: ["*"],
          principals: sharingAccountsPrincipals,  // array of AccountPrincipals with list of sharing accounts IDs
          conditions: [
            {
              "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "oam:ResourceTypes": [
                  "AWS::CloudWatch::Metric",
                  "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
                  "AWS::XRay::Trace",
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      ],
    });


    const monitoringAccountSink = new CfnSink(this, "MonitoringAccountSink", {
      name: "MonitoringAccountSink",
      policy: monitoringAccountPolicyDocument,
    });

    const sharingAccountsLinks = sharingAccounts.map((account) => {
      const accountName = account.accountName;
      const accountLink = new CfnLink(
        this,
        `SharingAccountLink-${accountName}`,
        {
          resourceTypes: ["AWS::Logs::LogGroup", "AWS::XRay::Trace, AWS::CloudWatch::Metric"],
          sinkIdentifier: monitoringAccountSink.ref,
          labelTemplate: "$AccountName",
        }
      );
    });
```

So I expected it would create both a sink and links and all IAM required roles will be created under the hood.

But Cloudformation is trhowing an error when trying to create a Sink:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::Oam::Sink"
```

Why could it be? Should I add some more configuration to monitoring account? Is there some IAM settings being missed?
Role I use to deploy all of this has admin permissions.

Comment: The `CfnSomething` constructs you are using are so-called [L1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) constructs. L1 constructs correspond 1:1 with CloudFormation resources.  You are responsible for adding the necessary roles, permissions or supporting resources.  The CDK's L2 and L3 constructs do this for you.

Comment: yep but I just don't understand what exactly I should add as it's not very clear from the docs

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
const policy = {
      Version: "2012-10-17",
      Statement: [
        {
          Action: ["oam:CreateLink", "oam:UpdateLink"],
          Effect: "Allow",
          Resource: "*",
          Principal: { AWS: [sharingAccountsPrincipals] },
          Condition: {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": { "oam:ResourceTypes": ["AWS::CloudWatch::Metric", "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"] },
          },
        },
      ],
    };

const monitoringAccountSink = new oam.CfnSink(this, "sinkMainAccount", {
  name: "monitoring-sink",
  policy: policy,
});
```

Comment: sharingAccountsPrincipals if array it will give an error. I put the comma-separated accounts.